# Database Insertion with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables 
**tbl_user** - id, username, password (id is pk and auto-incremented) 
**tbl_userprofile** - id, userid, name, surname, gender, nationality,address, mobile, department, email, question, answer. 
userid is a foreign key in tbl_userprofile referencing id in tbl_user
I'm trying insert a new user into **tbl_userprofile**. To get the userid in **tbl_userprofile** My approach is to use a select statement to get the id form **tbl_user** but i'm not sure how to structure the `WHERE` clause.

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_userprofile (userid, name, surname, gender, nationality, address, mobile, department, email, question, answer) VALUES
```

`('(SELECT id from tbl_user WHERE *something*) ', '$name','$surname','$gender','$nationality','$address','$mobile','$department','$email','$question','$answer')";`
How do i structure my WHERE clause? or can i approach this in a different way?
NOTE: I thought i should mention that the insertion into **tbl_user** and **tbl_userprofile** is handled two different scripts because the forms are on two different pages.

Comment: Will there always be a one-to-one correlation between rows in tbl_user and tbl_userprofile? If so, why are they separate tables?

Comment: yes it's a one-to-one correlation. I made it like this to separate log in details from profile details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INSERT SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_userprofile (userid, name, surname, gender, nationality, address, mobile, department, email, question, answer) 
SELECT id, '$name', '$surname', '$gender', '$nationality', '$address','$mobile', '$department', '$email', '$question', '$answer'
FROM tbl_user 
WHERE *something*
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: But isn't this similar to what i'm doing? i'm having problems structuring the where clause because the forms are on different scripts. For example i could use the username to get the id but then the forms are on different scripts.

Comment: You are using insert into, not insert into select. Your where clause could be discussed in another topic I suppose.